# How to bulk rename as name1.ext, name2.ext, name3.ext....... in all sub folders using cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

I have tried the following code it shows operator missing. I tried in many ways but still something or the other error pops up.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var = " %cd% "
set i=1

forfiles /P %var % /S /M *.png /C "cmd /C set /a i=i+1 ren *.png Screenshot(!i!).png"
```

Someone please help me with this code I will be very glad ^_^

<--------------------------------------------------
Edited Later --------------------------------------------------------->

I am extremely sorry people but I wanted to
number the files in each folder separately starting from 1

Comment: what is the original file name?

Comment: Screenshot (num).png the num here varies they are in random number ranging from 1000-4000

Comment: list your folder tree and files, and which file you want to rename

Comment: That is huge bro... I have a main folder "Slides" inside that there are some 8 folders and each folder again has some 3 folders and there I have in each folder some 100 image files

So in total I have 100*3*8 2400 images files

Comment: If you take a look at the help, `cmd /?` you'll note **`/V:ON`** which would usually be necessary if you are using delayed expanson; also to concatenate commands you'd need to use **`&`** or **`&&`**. In addition why wouldn't you just use `/P "%CD%"`, and would you not need to use an `If [Not] Exist` type statement before renaming with the counter?

Comment: `set var = " %cd% "` sets a variable `var` + _space_ to the value _space_ + `"` + _space_ + `%cd%` + _space_ + `"`, which is not what you want, I guess. Anyway, you do not care about the original numbers in the file names, do you?

Comment: Yeah I don't care the numbers of original I just want to rename the original names with fine name from 1 2 3 and so on...

Comment: After you have edited the question -- check out my [adapted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441967)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might work for you:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise variables:
set "NAME=Screenshot"
set "PREV="
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    dir /S /B /A:-D "*.png"
') do (
    rem // Store current file path and extension:
    set "FILE=%%~F" & set "PDIR=%%~dpF" & set "EXT=%%~xF"
    rem // Check whether parent directory path changed:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if /I not "!PDIR!"=="!PREV!" (
        endlocal
        rem // Parent directory path changed, so reset counter:
        set /A "COUNT=0"
    ) else endlocal
    rem // Increment index counter:
    set /A "COUNT+=1"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks in file paths:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Actually rename files:
    ECHO ren "!FILE!" "!NAME!(!COUNT!)!EXT!"
    endlocal
    rem // Store parent path of current file:
    set "PREV=%%~dpF"
)
endlocal
```

After having tested the output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command** in front of `ren`!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT Changed the batch to fit new requirements.**

- Since current folder is the default you don't need to excplicitly set
  it
- forfiles will list all single files so your `ren *.png` won't include the path (if you insist on using forfiles use @path see forfiles /?
- I suggest using a for /R to iterate all folders and a for /f parsing dir output in each folder.

---

```
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

For /R %%A in (.) Do (
    Pushd %%A
    set i=0
    For /f "delims=" %%B in ('Dir /B/A-D "*.png" 2^>Nul ') Do (
        Set /A i+=1
        Echo Ren "%%~fB" "Screenshot(!i!).png"
    )
    PopD
)
```

If the output looks OK remove the echo in front of `Ren`

Comment: I tried the batch command I guess it worked but the thing is I want everytime the file name start from 1 2 3 and so on... For example if I have 2 subfolders as foo1 and foo2 and foo1 has 27 files and foo2 has 54 files then I want the renaming like 1 to 27 in foo1 and 1 to 54 in foo2 .

I hope I am clear.

Comment: I understand, but this information should be put in your [edited question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45437751/edit)

Comment: I am extremely sorry for this do forgive me. Can I edit and add this info now in question ?

Comment: Just click the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you bro I did that... Hope now I am clear to all the people thank you for your code which made me realised lately though what exactly I need :)

Comment: Batch changed, should do now as required.

Comment: I checked the echo it is trying to rename the files in the main directory only it is not going into subdirectory

Comment: Changed the batch to step into each folder and back with pushd/popd. Shoiuld work now.

Comment: Thanks Its Working :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to rename all .png files. When you are satisfied that the files are being renamed, remove `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

=== Rename-PngFiles.ps1

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File *.png |
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName `
            -NewName "Screenshot($(Get-Variable -ValueOnly i; $i++)).png" -WhatIf 
    }
```

=== In a cmd.exe shell or .bat file script

```
powershell -NoProfile -File Rename-PngFiles.ps1
```